# Passing JSON data into another activity and accessing certain parts of JSON Array (and position) in the new activity

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-intent

I am passing a JSON Array/object through and `Intent.putExtra` into a new activity where I want to use certain strings inside that array. I want to know how to link to the JSON being passed through and how I can access the String Extras??

```
    {
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CompanyAdapter.CompanyViewHolder 
    holder, final int position) {
        //CompanyItem currentItem = companyItem.get(position);
    //
        //holder.mtitleText.setText(currentItem.getmCompanyTitle());
       //holder.mnumberText.setText(currentItem.getmCompanyDescription());
       //holder.mNodeText.setText(currentItem.getmNodeCount());

        Log.d(TAG, "currentItemNode: " + position);

        holder.mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Log.d(TAG, "Clicked: " + position);
                Object dataSet = null;

                try {
                    dataSet = companyItem.get(position);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "TEST: " + String.valueOf(dataSet));

                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), 
       NodeDrawActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("jsonObject", dataSet.toString());
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                Log.d(TAG, "TEST2: " + dataSet);

            }
        });

        try{






      holder.mtitleText.setText(companyItem.getJSONObject(position) 
     .getString("title"));
            holder.mnumberText.setText 
     (companyItem.getJSONObject(position).getString("description"));
            //holder.mNodeText.setText 
     (companyItem.getJSONObject(position).getString("company_status"));
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + companyItem);

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount:");
        return companyItem.length();
    }


    }






    ----------------------------New Activity On Create---------------------





        {
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.node_activity);

        mTitleText = findViewById(R.id.comanyName);
        mDescriptionText = findViewById(R.id.descTitle);
        mOfficerText = findViewById(R.id.officerText);
        mAppCount = findViewById(R.id.appCount);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //intent.putExtra("jsonObject", companyData.toString());
        String companyName = intent.getStringExtra("jsonObject");
        String companyDescription = intent.getStringExtra("description");

        Log.d(TAG, "companyDescription: " + companyDescription);

        Log.d(TAG, "companyData: " + companyName);

    //        Object companyData = null;
    //
    //        try {
    //            companyData = companyItem.get();
    //        } catch (JSONException e) {
    //            e.printStackTrace();
    //        }



    //mTitleText.getText(companyItem.getJSONObject().getString(mtitleText);
       // 

     mTitleText.setText 
    (companyItem.getJSONObject(position).getString("title"));
       // 



    mnumberText.setText
    companyItem.getJSONObject(position).getString("description"));





    // 

   holder.mNodeText.setText(companyItem.getJSONObject(position).getString 
    ("com 
    pany_status"));
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + companyItem);

    }
```

I want to receive the Title name and description as well as position from the other activity intent

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialise your object 1st in your second activity With Gson.

```
String dataSet = intent.getStringExtra("jsonObject");
Gson gsonData = new Gson();
Object data = gsonData.fromJson(dataSet, Object.class);

String companyName = data.getJSONObject(position) 
 .getString("title"));
String companyDescription = data.getJSONObject(position).getString("description"));
```

Something along those lines to get your JSON data out of your original object because right now its still just a string.